# Проблема с кареткой в angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Добрый день!
Есть директива, которая оборачивает input, добавляет к input некий атрибут и затем компилирует этот элемент.

```
directive('formGroup', function($compile) {
        return {
            templateUrl:"dir_form_group.html",
            restrict: 'E',
            transclude: true,
            scope:{
                staticVal: "="
            },
            link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
                   var $model = $('[ng-model]', element);
                   $model.attr('attr', '{{attr}}');
                   $compile($model)(scope.$parent);
            }
        }
    })
<form-group static-val = "{'title':'Field 1'}">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model = "objVar.var">
</form-group>
```

Проблема заключается в том, что если ng-model присвоена переменная, как свойство объекта, например objVar.var то начинается проблема с кареткой.
Если я в середине текста начинаю что-то вводить каретка сразу перелетает в конец текста.

А если ng-model присвоена обычная переменная var, то такой проблемы не наблюдается.

Посмотреть пример можно в [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/5jAg3X2vrWWCDEEURnax?p=preview).

Как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: Это из-за перекомпиляции в `link`

Answer (score 0):

Из-за перекомпиляции элемента в `link` значение обновляется.
То же самое можно сделать без `$compile`:

```
function (scope, element, attributes) {
  var attr = $parse('attr')(scope.$parent);
  $('[ng-model]', element).attr('attr', angular.toJson(attr));
}
```

Comment: А для textarea такого эффекта почему-то нет [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/iaDaodBeQLYMGrphQ9fh?p=preview)

Comment: Скорее всего потому, что в `textarea` `ngModel` маппится в DOM, а не в `value`